# Is there phrase describing opposite action of hanging out clothes?

Tags: phrase-request

Let's say you hang out clothes to dry under the sun. After drying, you get the clothes back. Is there any phrase describing the action getting back the clothes from the clothesline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard this described most often as "taking the laundry in", or "taking in the laundry".